# AEM 6.3 site map page

Tags: aem

Is there a build in way to create a site map page. I'm not looking for a sitemap.xml generator, that we have, but a page that will list all the page named and a link.

My GoogleFu keeps bringing up the sitemap.xml generation.

Comment: I'm looking at the List component, V2 may be a good starting point.

Comment: As far as I know there is no out-of-the-box feature for that. Neither ACS Commons nor the We.Retail demo seem to have something so I guess you will have to write something like this for yourself. Overall, it is not that hard. Traverse your content tree downwards from your homepage, gather all pages that are not "hideInNav", render those pages as tree etc. For most of the stuff you should find examples in ACS Commons or We.Retail.

Comment: The List component seems to do this, but the output is a basic unordered list. When I put this together as a quick demo, it got paused as it exposed lots of pages that bad meta data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the foundation component under '/libs/foundation/components/sitemap' you could port this functionality into a custom component for your site

Comment: I think that's where we're going. It doesn't keep the structure, all the pages end up at the same level, but it's a start.

Thanks!